# How to ask for re-opening a question when having low reputation?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-reopen

I've asked [a question on the Chemistry Stack Exchange](//chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44513/is-it-true-that-human-cells-grow-in-levorotation) and my language was not clear enough. So it was put on hold because it looked like a question for Biology SE. Then I've asked [the same question on the Biology SE](//biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42870/is-it-true-that-human-cells-grow-in-levorotation), as advised. Then someone answered my question, because he understood that my language was unclear but the question was good for Chemistry SE.
But then the question was closed for cross-posting.
Then I changed the question so now it's clear that it's good for the Chemistry SE.
Then I even deleted the question on the Biology SE.
So now the question is valid but how can I ask for reopening it? I only have 11 reputation so I don't have the "vote re-open" button available.

And since everybody forgot about that question, now it can't be re-opened.

I think there should be a mechanism accessible for the people with low reputation in order to allow them to show to the community that they solved the problems with their closed questions.

And I think there should no be time limitations for such things (like: "if you re-write the question in X days then.."). Once the question becomes valid, the users should be able to ask for re-opening it.

The user "Dr. Wily's Apprentice" expressed such an opinion very well in [this answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/63230/301091).

Comment: I forgot to mention, I prefer not to ask it on meta of that SE site, because I think that the "meta" sites should not be flooded with unlocking requests.

Comment: So it's better to flood Meta.SE with them instead? ;) Really, there's no reason to be wary of it. That's what the meta site is for. Every site has a meta and part of the job of it is to discuss questions about the site **including** "why was this post closed", "I've edited my post, can it please be nominated for reopening (if not, what else can I do to improve it?)" and the like. They're dull places (on smaller sites) on the best of days... nothing like livening them up a bit with *some* activity!

Answer (score 7):

If you edit a question within five days of it being closed, it goes into the Reopen Votes review queue, where users with the [Cast Close And Reopen Votes privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) (requires 3k rep on graduated sites, 500 rep on beta sites) can decide whether it's acceptable in its new form. If the consensus is Leave Closed, you just blew your one chance - questions only get one edit-induced trip through the RV queue. Note that it might take a while for enough users with the Reopen privilege to vote to reopen questions, especially on small sites where there aren't many such users in the first place.

If the five-day or one-edit window is closed and you're *sure* you fixed all the problems with the question, you can post on the site's meta. Participating in meta requires 5 rep or more, but it looks like you have that. Make the case for your question to be reopened, and people will probably do that. **Danger!** A low-effort meta post, especially if the question you want reopened is not fixed, will likely attract additional downvotes.

If you had 15 rep, you could flag your own post with a custom reason. <s>(Can sub-15 users flag their own posts?)</s> Clearly ask for it to be reopened, and in as much detail as is possible with that text field, explain why it should be. If you're right, your question will be reopened and the flag will be marked helpful. Conversely, if your question is still unacceptable, you'll get a declined flag on top of it.

Answer (score 4):

Editing the question should already have added it to the reopen queue. That's part of the editing process. It's done regardless of your reputation... but it's only good during a short window of the question being closed.

If you've passed that window, you have a few options... there's the ones Ben mentioned and other options include:

- Visit the [Chemistry Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table) room and ask if the question has been improved sufficiently to be voted to reopen.
- One of the mods has already commented on your question... you could post a directed comment at him (@Martin - マーチン) and ask if your question was sufficiently fixed and could be reopened.

The latter option is slightly problematic as he would have to believe it's good enough to reopen unilaterally... but it's still an option.